# How to unlock special demon contacts?

Tags: persona-2-eternal-punishment

Some party members can perform unique demon contacts together after performing some specific steps to unlock them. What are all the different unlockable contacts and how do I unlock them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Flamenco de la Pasion** Ulala + Katsuya

1. Talk with Ulala inside the Lunar Palace before Sky Museum.
2. Talk with Katsuya at the Sumaru Prison after Sky Museum but before you find Makimura.
3. The contact will become available after you are reunited with Ulala.

**Flamenco de la Pasion** Ulala + Katsuya + Ellen

4. Talk with Ellen at the Lunar Palace before Sumaru TV.

To add Tatsuya, speak to him inside Sumaru Prison before the subway.

**Dance of Passion special** Ulala + Katsuya + Tatsuya

1. Unlock Flamenco de la Pasion.
2. Talk with Tatsuya at the Sumaru Prison before going to the Subway.

**100 Stories** Ellen + Ulala + Tatsuya/Baofu

1. Talk with Tatsuya and Baofu inside the Trish's Fountain accessible via the Sky Museum.
2. Talk with Ellen and Ulala inside the Trish's Fountain accessible via Sumaru TV.
3. The contact will become available after you finish Sumaru TV.

**Song of a Baseball Fanatic** Baofu + Nate

1. Talk with Baofu inside Shiraishi in Hirasaka before entering the Sewers.
2. Talk with Nate inside Sumaru TV before entering Smile Mall.

**Cynical People** Nate + Baofu

1. Talk with Baofu and Nate inside Parabellum before Smile Mall.

**Investigation of Terror** Katsuya + Baofu

**Investigation of Terror (Scam Special)** Katsuya + Baofu + Ulala

**Investigation of Terror (Pervert Special)** Katsuya + Baofu + Ellen

**Alcohol, tears, men and women** Baofu + Ulala + Katsuya

Unlocked by story progression event:

> Factory complete

**Adult's Excuse** Baofu + Tatsuya

**Child's Claim** Tatsuya + Baofu

Unlocked by story progression event:

> Subway complete

**Brother's Kindness** Katsuya + Tatsuya

**Comparing Heights** Tatsuya + Katsuya

Unlocked by story progression event:

> Killing the golden effigies of Lisa, Eikichi and Jun at Ameno Torifune